# message sending start date time

Tags: android, sqlite, sms, smsmanager

i have a chat application in which I am sending message to numbers that is being sent successfully. now I want that I should take date time as input and message should be send for that that particular date time. I am saving date time in sqlite. For this I have two asynctask in while loop in first message is being sent successfully. In other AsyncTask I am getting all those message which have not been sent. My Asynctask is:

```
while (true) {
String[] jobsNumbers = numbers.toArray(new String[numbers.size()]);
new SendJobs().execute(jobsNumbers);
destroy = true;
cursor = databaseHelperClass.getMessagesNotSent();
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    do {
    Id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
    jobMessageNotSent=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Message"));
    startDatetimecursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("StartDatetime"));
    isComplete=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("isComplete"));
} while (cursor.moveToNext());
new SendMessages().execute(Id);
}
```

In this asynctask I am getting that message which are not sent but saved in database.Now my question is that while loop should remain true and message should be sent only once. For getting message my query is

```
public Cursor getJobMessagesNotSent() {
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select * from Jobs where isSent= 0 and 
datetime('now') > senddate";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain the problem clearly

Comment: I explain it. suppose i have saved datetime of tomorrow 7 a.m in my database. I want that message should be sent at this time. my while loop should remain true and message should be sent only once. In my asynctask all those messages come whose  datetime('now') > senddate .
Now my question is how I will break while loop when message is sent and that message should not be sent again and again and message should be sent according to their datetime which I have saved in database.

Comment: IT IS WRONG USE Alarm Manager for sending  message on perticular time . and what is `new SendMessages().execute(Id);` check database time and current time then send message it will send message once on time